# Acessar propriedades sem saber nome

Tags: php, classes, propriedade, reflexão

É possível dentro da classe acessar todas suas definições *(propriedades)* sem ter seus nomes?

Por exemplo, se eu crio uma instância duma classe `$classe = new Classe()`, e vou definindo coisas nela:

```
$classe->ComprarFile = true;
$classe->comidaDoCachorro = false;
$classe->valorDoDolar = '50 reais';
```

Seria possível acessar essas propriedades na classe sem saber o nome delas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tem. Existem basicamente duas opções. Uma é usando [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($classe));
```

E a outra é [iterar sobre o objeto](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php):

```
foreach ($classe as $key => $value) print "$key => $value\n";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/ListAll.php).

Aí dá para usar a criatividade para acessar de formas diferentes usando estas técnicas. O importante é que no fundo as classes são *arrays* associativos. Então você tem fácil os nomes e os valores de todos os membros.

Comment: tem como fazer isso dentro da classe em sí?

Comment: Sim, pode.. O exemplo que eu usei foi retirado na página da documentação que faz justamente isto. Ele usar o `$this`. Só tome cuidado para não usar um recursos desnecessário e conceitualmente errado.